# jQuery: Moving a cell and header to a new table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(".list.list_container").each(function () {
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.append(
    jQuery("<tr>").append(
         $table.find("tr:first td:eq(3)"),"<td></td><td></td>")
    )
});
```

```css
td {
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="list list_container">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>one</th>
  <th>two</th>
  <th>three</th>
  <th>four</th>
</tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="blah_row">
            <td class="first">Blah1</td>
            <td class="second">Blah2</td>
            <td class="third">Blah3</td>
            <td class="last">Blah4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/qsjhcfd1/

I'm trying to move one of the Blahs and its corresponding header to the second row. Removing the `thead` works fine so there's where I'm having trouble with. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
Image of expected result

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you asking how to move the Column?

Comment: Just updated the post with an image of the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8dpwaqfk/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function addRow(table) {
    // Append a Row to a Specific Table
    $("<tr>").appendTo($("tbody", table));
  }

  function addCell(rIndex, cIndex, table) {
    // Append a Cell after a specific Row and Column to a specific Table 
    $("<td>").insertAfter($("tbody tr", table).eq(rIndex).find("td").eq(cIndex));
  }

  function moveCellDown(cIndex, table) {
    var cell;
    if ($("tbody > tr", table).length == 1) {
      addRow(table);
    }
    $("tbody tr:eq(0) > td", table).each(function(i, el) {
      if (i == cIndex) {
        cell = $(el).detach();
        addCell(0, (i - 1), table);
        cell.appendTo($("tbody tr:eq(1)", table));
      } else {
        $("tbody tr:eq(1)", table).append($("<td>"));
      }
    });
  }

  moveCellDown(2, $(".list"));
});
```

Using `.detach()` can be very helpful with this type of script. See More:

https://api.jquery.com/detach/

**Update**

After seeing your Image, I would suggest something like:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8dpwaqfk/37/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  function addRow(table) {
    // Append a Row to a Specific Table
    $("<tr>", {
      class: "added_row"
    }).appendTo($("tbody", table));
  }

  function moveColumn(cIndex, table) {
    var head = $("thead th", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    var cell = $("tbody tr:eq(0) td", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    addRow(table);
    head.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(1)", table);
    addRow(table);
    cell.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(2)", table);
  }

  moveColumn(2, $(".list"));
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of this comes close to expected results from updated image link in the question. OP actually wants two new rows with `<th>` from `<thead>` row in one ... very messy IMO

Comment: @charlietfl please review the Update

Comment: Yeah..looks better!. Can't get straight answer from OP what real use case is or I would have put more effort in

Comment: Thanks Twisty! @charlietfl I've commented the use case to your post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(".list.list_container").each(function () {
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.append('<tr>');
    $('th:contains("three")').appendTo('tbody tr:last');
    //$('th:contains("three")').appendTo('tbody tr:last').wrapInner('<td />').contents().unwrap(); if u need change th to td 
    $table.append('<tr>');
    $('td:contains("Blah3")').appendTo('tbody tr:last');    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mysmx/qdyr3am7/2/

[image]